# Inheritance from base class that implements tableview delegate and data souce methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have two classes that inherit from certain base class. In these classes I have same tableview methods, so I decided to move all that logics to the base class. There is no nibs files, all in code. But the base class does not responds to tableview events for some reason. Is it right to move that logics to the base class, or is there some known problem, or am I missing something in my implementation?

I'm just assigning:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

And then implementing:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
        return 320;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return [self.imagesArray count];
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"mediaCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0f, 320.0f)] autorelease];

            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0f, 320.0f)];
            imageView.tag = 1;
            [cell addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];
        }
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [imageView setImageWithURL:url];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return self.filterBar.bounds.size.height;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return self.filterBar;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put some code. how do you define its delegate. Please specify

Comment: Did you accidentally leave some dangling functions in your child class?  The child class, as per object oriented rules, will be checked first.  It will only call the base class implementation if either a) There is no implementation in the child class or b) the child class calls `super`  Also, did you check to make sure table view wasn't `nil` at that point?

Comment: There is no implementations of tableview methods in child class and uitableview isn't nil

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the tableview delegate methods, I think you are missing to add the  category in the definition of the base class, can you clarify if the methods are the delegates used by the UITableview ?